# How to return java list in HSQLDB stored procedure?

Tags: java, stored-procedures, hsqldb

I am trying to return custom list from my stored procedure in hsqldb
Below is the sample code, can anyone please help how to return java list in HSQLDB stored procedure?

```
CREATE TYPE list
EXTERNAL NAME 'java.util.List'
LANGUAGE JAVA;

CREATE PROCEDURE MyStorProc (
    test_column1 VARCHAR(30),
    test_column2 VARCHAR(30),
    OUT Out_column_Name list)
    PARAMETER STYLE JAVA
    LANGUAGE JAVA
    READS SQL DATA
    DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
    EXTERNAL NAME 'com.mypackage.name.getList'
;
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return a `java.util.List` from a procedure.

Define the OUT parameter as `OUT out_column_name VARCHAR(100) ARRAY` or any array of a supported HSQLDB type (excluding LOB types).

The `com.mypackage.name.getList` must then return a java.sql.Array object. You can create such arrays with the org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCArrayBasic class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please share any example which will help me.

Comment: Can we return array of list for the above? Please share any example.